# matplotlib 1.3.1 can't specify 'save as' for figures

Tags: matplotlib, save

The title almost says it all. I have version matplotlib-1.3.1 (and I've tried this now on OS X and Ubuntu 13.10) installed. When I create an image which I would like to save to my machine, I am unable to change the field entitled 'save as' from the default figure_1.png.

Does anyone know what's going on here? For the moment I'm getting around it by either using savefig() or by saving it as the default value and renaming the plot before I generate any new ones. Going back a version is not an option for me.

Comment: what backend are you using?

Comment: and I can not reproduce this.

Comment: I'm using Qt4Agg. I've checked with a bunch of people I work with and they're all having the same problem, too. Maybe when we all updated at some point it changed the default backend?

Comment: Are you running this through `ipython`?  I seem to recall there being some strange interaction modal dialog bug that get fixed recently (I am running ipython 2.0.x)

Comment: No, this is not through ipython. For what it's worth, my ipython version is:  IPython 1.1.0

Comment: What backend are you using? I may try switching to something else and see if it takes care of it.

Comment: qt4agg + pysides.  Does it work through ipython? I suspect something funny is going on with the event loop.

Comment: Wow - Yes, it is definitely working through ipython. Very strange.

Comment: I restarted my machine (Ubuntun 13.10), which seems to fix the issue. However, on OSX 10.9 (and on 10.8) it seems to still be broken. On that machine it's 1.3.1 and the backend is 'MacOSX'. Any ideas?

Comment: no.  Understanding how the backends hook up to the event loop/the magic ipython does are on my (very long) todo list.  I know almost nothing about the macosx backend (not a mac user), but there are long-running issues related to it's event loop (mostly about blitting).  There is also issues with what version of python you are using (framework build vs not, system vs python.org).